# website navigation bar hiding behind behind <main>

Tags: html, css

I am building myself a website and have tried to implement a fixed navigation bar.

**HEAD HTML:**

```
<header id="header" style="background: url(images/bg.png);background-position:center bottom; width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; height:550px;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;">

<div class="nav-menu">
  <div id="nav-menu-container">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-active">home</li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="books.html">books</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </header>
```

As you can see I have a background image for the header and when I scroll, the navigation works perfectly staying fixed to the top of the screen as the image slowly rolls upwards.

However, when I scroll enough to hit the beginning of my content the navigation bar disappears behind.

(A snippet of the code that begins after the header closes and when the navigation disappears behind)

```
   <main> 
  <section id="intro">
    <div id="introleft">
        <h1>left</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="introright">
        <h1>right</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-menu {
width: 100%;
height: 0 auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:auto;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
.nav-menu ul {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.nav-menu li a:hover {
    color: grey;
}
.menu-active {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try  increasing the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of your nav bar in css.

```
.nav-menu {
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: don't forget that position on the element needs to be set for z-index to work

Comment: how do I set the position in this instance?

Comment: Position is already set in your code, its the position: fixed in .nav-menu